# got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk' on genric view

Tags: python, django, django-generic-views

I am trying to use Built-in `UpdateView` & `DeleteView`, And I am keep getting TypeErrors, with the Exception Value:

> *get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'*

**views.py**

```
class SeqRunUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    form_class = Sequencing_RunsForm
    model = Sequencing_Runs

class SeqRunDelete(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Sequencing_RunsForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('seq_run-private')
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^private/Samples/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.SampleUpdate.as_view(), name='sample-update'),
url(r'^private/Samples/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/del$', views.SampleUpdate.as_view(), name='sample-delete'),
```

**models.py**

```
class Sequencing_Runs(models.Model):
    seq = models.CharField (max_length=250, unique=True, verbose_name='Sequence')
    date= models.DateField (auto_now=False, verbose_name='Date')
    classifaction = models.IntegerField(choices=CLASSIFACTION_CHOICES, default=1)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('table:seq_run-add')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.seq
```

**Template**

```
<td><form action="{% url 'table:seq_run-update' seq.pk %}" method="get" style="display: inline;">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                        </button>
                    </form></td>
                    <td><form action="{% url 'table:seq_run-delete' seq.pk %}" method="get" style="display: inline;">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                        </button>
                    </form></td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `SampleUpdate` in your `urls.py` but I can't see that class anywhere in your `views.py`, you instead have `SeqRunUpdate` & `SeqRunDelete`. Use the respective view class in your urls and the error should go away.

Comment: oh i have just notice that i have confuesed between the urls thank you very much i was stacked on this mistake for a day